# How to create moveable (by mouse) buttons at runtime c#

Tags: winforms, user-controls, runtime

I am using the following code to create buttons at run-time but how to make them movable (drag-able with mouse on screen anywhere)

```
var b = new Button();
    b.Text = "My Button";
    b.Name= "button"; 
    b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
    b.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseUp);
    b.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseDown);
    b.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseMove);
    this.myPanel.Controls.Add(b);
```

I have tried to work with mouse events but could not make them move according to mouse pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the mouse can move outside the button while dragging, you have to use the [Control.Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.
This sample let's you move the buttons not on the entire screen, but within the bounds of its parent container (or outside it, then hidden, which should probably be prevented).

```
private Point Origin_Cursor;
private Point Origin_Control;
private bool BtnDragging = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b = new Button();
    b.Text = "My Button";
    b.Name = "button";
    //b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
    b.MouseUp += (s, e2) => { this.BtnDragging = false; };
    b.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseDown);
    b.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseMove);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(b);
}

private void b_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button ct = sender as Button;
    ct.Capture = true;
    this.Origin_Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
    this.Origin_Control = ct.Location;
    this.BtnDragging = true;
}

private void b_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.BtnDragging)
    {
        Button ct = sender as Button;
        ct.Left = this.Origin_Control.X - (this.Origin_Cursor.X - Cursor.Position.X);
        ct.Top = this.Origin_Control.Y - (this.Origin_Cursor.Y - Cursor.Position.Y);
    }
}
```