# How to save location of movable button in visual basic winform?

Tags: vb.net

I have a movable button. the new location is save in my setting once it is mouse up event. when I move the button, sometimes the button disappear, after I re run it, it completely disappear.

How to save the button location before I close the app?

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim newpoint As New Point


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If My.Settings.button1_x70123454440211bghff > 0 Or My.Settings.button1_y70123454440211bghff > 0 Then
            Me.Button1.Location = New Point(My.Settings.button1_x70123454440211bghff, My.Settings.button1_y70123454440211bghff)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

            newpoint = Control.MousePosition
            newpoint = Control.MousePosition
            newpoint.X -= x
            newpoint.Y -= y
            Button1.Location = newpoint
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
        x = Control.MousePosition.X - Button1.Location.X
        y = Control.MousePosition.Y - Button1.Location.Y
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp
        My.Settings.button1_x70123454440211bghff = x
        My.Settings.button1_y70123454440211bghff = y
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        My.Settings.richtextbox1 = RichTextBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are saving `x` and `y` to your settings. What do those variables actually represent? certainly not the location of the `Button`, so why are you saving them? If you want to save the location of the `Button` then actually do that, i.e. save the `Left` and `Top` property values.

Comment: You'll have to prevent the user from moving the button outside of the window.  Test against 0 and Me.ClientSize.Width - Button1.Width, same for Height.  That produces interesting mouse problems, so best to cancel movement with a Boolean variable.

Comment: [Don't move the Labels outside a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317811/7444103)

Comment: In `Form_Load`, `If My.Settings.button1_x70123454440211bghff > 0 Or My.Settings.button1_y70123454440211bghff > 0 Then` should be `And`?

Comment: Make sure that the Setting is scoped to User.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560127/832052) for button movement, and add some checks to keep the control within its parent container. For the setting, I like to keep things simple, and will take advantage of the ability of Visual Studio to store a struct in the settings, so instead I will use a `System.Drawing.Point`

[image]

Now you ask "How to save the button location before I close the app?" Well you can do it in Form_Close, or do it in the MouseUp event. Since you do it in the MouseUp, I will do the same. And I will load the last position in Form_Load

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private initialCursorPosition As System.Drawing.Point
    Private intialButtonPosition As System.Drawing.Point
    Private buttonIsMoving As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Button1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
        Dim b = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        initialCursorPosition = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
        intialButtonPosition = b.Location
        buttonIsMoving = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp
        buttonIsMoving = False
        My.Settings.Button1Location = DirectCast(sender, Button).Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove
        If buttonIsMoving Then
            Dim b = DirectCast(sender, Button)
            Dim newX = intialButtonPosition.X - (initialCursorPosition.X - Cursor.Position.X)
            Dim newY = intialButtonPosition.Y - (initialCursorPosition.Y - Cursor.Position.Y)
            newX = Math.Max(Math.Min(newX, b.Parent.ClientSize.Width - b.Width), 0)
            newY = Math.Max(Math.Min(newY, b.Parent.ClientSize.Height - b.Height), 0)
            b.Location = New Point(newX, newY)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1.Location = My.Settings.Button1Location
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]